# Is there a way to have the close window button (X) call a method before actually closing the window?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

In a windows form project in C#/.net/Visual Studio 2010, if someone hits the close window button, I want to disable some other things in the program as a consequence.  Is there a method call for hitting "X" that I can extend?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two events that you should use are `FormClosing` and `FormClosed`.

In the .Net Framework verion 2.0 these events replaced the obsolete `Closing` and `Closed` events.

The reason for the new events was that the old ones were not raised when the `Application.Exit` method was called.

An example of the usage of the `FormClosing` event is below:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Really close this form?", string.Empty, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

That code simply asks the user if they want to close the form, and if No is selected, it then cancels the event. You can put any logic you require in the event handler.

---

The MSDN article on `Form.Closing` is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx) and includes references about why the event was made obsolete. The reference for `Form.FormClosing` is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Cool!!  I was pretty sure there was something easy like that.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Your window class publishes two events for this purpose:

[Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx) allows you to cancel the close if it's inappropriate

[Closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed.aspx) allows you to react on close.

Answer (score 0):

Just register a handler on the [FormClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) event.

Comment: Isn't the "FormClosed" event too late, after the form has already been closed?? You need "FormClosing" instead, I believe

Comment: Nothing in the question suggests that `FormClosing` would be needed over `FormClosed`. But I do admit that my answer is incomplete for not mentioning the second event, as other answers have.